# DHCP server does not include NTP server addresses in the DHCP ACK message

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, ntp, connman

I am capturing DHCP packets with tcpdump. The client sends a DHCP request asking for the DHCP configuration which contains a request for NTP servers but in the DHCP ACK message sent by the router there is no NTP server information. 
Shouldn't the server answer with the NTP server's IPs as it does with the domain name servers? What am I missing?

I attatch screen shots of the request and ack messages

tcpdump command used:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n port 67 and port 68 -w capture.pcap -v
```

DHCP REQUEST:

[image: DHCP Request message]

DHCP ACK:

[image: Information received from the server in DHCP Acknowledge message]

Comment: Which DHCP server are you using? Why _should_ it include NTP servers? Does it even know about NTP servers?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Sorry @jww , I wasn't aware of that. I placed the question in Linux Stack Exchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Linux operating system question and not a programming question. In addition, it is duped on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

It depends on whether the DHCP server was configured to provide an NTP server. DHCP doesn't *have* to provide NTP parameters.

RFC 2132:

> 8.3. Network Time Protocol Servers Option
>
> This option specifies a list of IP addresses indicating NTP [18]
>   servers available to the client.  Servers SHOULD be listed in order
>   of preference.
>
> The code for this option is 42.  Its minimum length is 4, and the
>   length MUST be a multiple of 4.

Note the use of "SHOULD" as opposed to "MUST"